# Firebase CLI commands printing unexpected malicious looking response on Linux, The text has infinite number of word: 'testing'

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-cli, firebase-tools

I am using Ubuntu. 
I have recently installed **firebase-tools** using **npm** with the command as officially stated:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Also later unaware, installed another package locally in my project called **firebase**. Using the command:

```
npm install firebase
```

I'm facing huge issues thereafter, with no idea what is happening.
Whenever I run any firebase command (eg: firebase --help, firebase login, etc.) It's all giving me similar output which is shown as here:

```
    undefined
    undefined
    undefined
                                       !             H|H|H|H|H  
         H__________________________________             H|§|§|§|H           H|* * * * * *|---------------------|             H|§|∞|§|H  
         H| * * * * * |---------------------|             H|§|§|§|H           H|* * * * * *|---------------------|             H|H|H|H|H           H| * * * * * |---------------------|             H|H|H|H|H           
H|---------------------------------|          ===============        H|---------------------------------|            /| _   _ | 
         H|---------------------------------|            (| O   O |)          H|---------------------------------|            /|   U   |          H-----------------------------------             |  =/  |           H  
            _..._/            H    
          _|I/|_            H      _______/| H |/_______    H     /           / /          H    |          | | /         |  H    
|          ||o||          |  H    |    |     ||o||     |    |  H    |    |     ||o||     |    |  H   
Carl Pilcher
  
    tͭͭe͂ͥ ҉̥͓͎͕͝šͣ̀t͗͐͂i͋̔ ҉̮͔n̏̓ͫg̀̓ ̔̾t͐̐e͐͗s̐̎t̔͂iͧ͐n̄̔g͌̈ ͫ̋t̓̅̾ē̐s͋̆tͣ̚i͒̑nͪ͌g͋͆ ̏ͬ ҉̨̘͇ͅt̄̍é͊s̓̾tͩ̆ ҉̴̙iͫ̒̐ ҉̴̹͙͔͡n̑͋̌g̃̓ ͫͬ̎̌t̒̐̋e̔͌s̋͑tͯ̌ͩi̍̒nͦ́g͌ͦ ̇̊t̀ͫë͋̓sͣ͆t̊̓i̊̐n̓̀ ҉ ҉̟͇g͗̓ ͋̽t̊͒e͑̓s͛ͪ̍t̆ͮi̾̊n̏̑g̍̀
    t̉̈eͯ̓ ҉̘͢͡s͑̍͑̍t̑ͣiͧ̾n̑̎gͧ̐ ͣ̈̍tͤ̀ẻ̿s̓ͨt̽̄i̽́nͮͥg̅̅̋ ͬ̎ť̐͌ẽ̚s̎͌tͬ̇iͯ̄nͯ̌g̈̉ ͧͮ ҉̭͓t̔ͬeͬ̽s̈́̾ ҉͎̘tͮͭ ҉̨̜͇̗i͌͐nͥ̃g̀̊ ̌̍ṫ͌ͤeͦ́̉̌s̓͐t̍̓ī͒n̓ͥg͛ͮ ҉̱̫ ̍̔̆tͮ̋̉ ҉̹́e͊̿s̔ͮͬt͑̽iͫͦn̿̔g͑ͩ ͯ̔ ҉̣͠t͊́e͐ͤs̾̐t̓͛iͬ̂nͫ́g̏̿
    t̒̀ȅ̚ṡ͒ẗ͌iͨ̀n̑͛͋g̔͐ ͫ̚t̂̓̔e̿̃s̈̓ ҉̶̠͟ť̋i͌̉̔nͥ̓gͥ̈ ̐ͦt͌͗e͌̈̋sͯ̑ ҉̠̜ͅt̒ͫi͒ͤ ҉͇̗ͅn̈̓͂g̎̒ ͫͬtͦ͋e͆̎sͣ͌ ҉̠̪̰̘ẗ̅ͪi͊ͪ ҉̵̙̳ň͋g̔ ͪ͒̚ẗ̆ë̓s̓̌tͧͬi̓̆n̾́̌g̔ͮ ҉̪͔͟ ͬ́t̓̊e̾͆sͤ̆t͑ͫi̒ͭn̓͐͐͋g̍ͦ ̍̑ ҉̵̨t͗ͨ̏éͧs̓͂ͭ ҉̤̻̪t͊͗i̓̆̽n͐͛ ҉̤̺̝g͂ͦ
    tͨ̋eͨ͊s̊tͭ͑iͫ̓̆ǹͮg̅͊ ͮt́̚e̓̅s̾ͬ̃tͬ̒ï͊n̏ͧḡ̓ ̎ͮťͧë͊s͂̈̊tͣ̎iͥ̅n͋͑gͪ̆ ͭ̈t̀̈eͥ͆ ҉̰̳͔͜s̋̅t̎̏̇i̿͐n̋̃gͦͤ ̔̏ ҉̦̜͖͍t̀̇eͯ̓s͛t͂͆̂i̓̓n̅̌g̊̈ ҉̢̼̫̝ ͯͣtͫ̎eͯsͪ̈t̏̉ ҉̞̣̳̻ĭ̊ͩnͬ̊g̉ͮ̋ ̔̓t̊ͣe̊͊͊̌s̏̈t͋͌i͋ͥn̍ͨgͤ̈
    t̏̔e̅͑s͛ ҉̧̀t͌͊͌iͬ̈n͑͐g̋̐ ҉͈͠ ̓͗t̅̚ ҉͇ͅĕ͒ͧs̍̚t̃͗͂iͥͨn͂̄g̅̀ ̊ͭtͯ̓eͭ̈s̈ͭt͆̃̔i͊̈n̓̈ǵ̈ ͩͪ ҉͖̝͜tͤ̽ͦe̐ͬsͧͧ ҉̣͠t͂ͬi͆̚ ҉̙̜nͨ̋gͪ́ ̄̈ͫtͭ͗ͭẻ̽s̃ͮt̀̊i̓̓n̒̃̉g̉̏̽ ͯ̃ ҉̮͚̼͖͚t̏̄̚e͋ͬsͮͨtͬ̌iͦ̓nͪg̓̈ ̾̔ ҉̪̦̺͝t̽́eͮ̋s̎͋t̃́iͪ̈ňͤg̉̚
    t̀ͫȅ͋s̀̚t̔ͮïͦ̽̓nͮ̈gͪ̉͂ ̾͂tͩͧ̏e̓͊s̑ͥt̾̉iͦ̓̆n̂͒gͪ̅ ҉̕͘ ͨͯẗ̓ͭe̓̚s̿͐ ҉̥̳t̍ͭiͪ̌n̉̏ǵ̆ ͨ͊ ҉̧͡t̂ͧë̾̓ ҉̕s̋̌t̒̐ ҉̻̲́iͨ͋nͤ͋̚g̊̔ ̔͑ ҉̖͕tͮ̄ě̍ś̽t̏͆î͑nͧͣgͦ̔ ͐̔tͩ̚eͯͧs̈̑t̀̓ï̆ ҉ ҉̡̕ń̈gͨ̚ ̇̊tͭͬe̅̈̾sͩ̚t̓̄ͭ̚i̊̂n̈͐ ҉̶͙̬͕̰̻g͂ͧ
    t͋ͥ ҉̶̰́e͂̾ͮs̐̄t͊ͧiͥ̐nͬ̐g̈̄ ͌̈ ҉̡̗͞t͆̏ě͐sͧ̔t́ͣͣ ҉̦̳̲ì̿nͧ̀͆g̓͂ ҉͙̩̞ ̍̍̒t͊̅͑e̍̊̋s̄ͫ ҉̸̳t̉̄iͨ͒̐nͩ͑ ҉͉͉́́g̒̈ ̓̈t́ͬẽͤŝ̏͐t̽͗i͑̓nͮ̐ͧͦͥg̈́̚ ̐̍tͤͯe̔̍ ҉̧̟̻̗̣s͆̅t̓͒͒iͪͩn̔̀͊g̓̏ ̑ͮͣt̏ͭĕ͋̎sͪ̌ͦ̈t̿̅̒ ҉̛͢͠i̿͋͐nͥ̀g͛̑ ̑͒tͬ̓ ҉̸͡ēͫŝ̀tͪ̏i̊̐n̊ͨg͒̿
    tͮ͊e̓͐sͦ̾̀tͦ̃iͤͣͣnͣ̒g̊͋ ͫ̓͑t̅̽e͒̌ ҉̢̹͞ṡ͑tͭ̎ͨi͌̈̿n̉ͦͤ ҉̮͠gͦ͒̒ ̋̒t͆̚ė͛sͧ̃tͤ͌ ҉̬̥i̊̏̅n̓̏ġ̽ ̃́tͪ̈ẻ̀s͆̑͂ ҉̴t̄̅iͨ͊ǹ̚ ҉̢͚gͬ̄ ̅̌t̍̒e̒̈s̆tͬ̅ ҉̛ ҉̴̡i͗͒ ҉̦͝n͗̉g͌̊̈ ͒͆t͊̊ͧě͑s͆͑t̋ͧi͊͑n̓͊g͋͆ ̃̑t͂͒e̽̍ ҉̥̟͕s̓̆tͪ̍i̊͂n̈̊g̑͆
    t̃ͮe̅ͧ ҉̫͟͝s̓̈̓t̊̇ǐ́͛ ҉̶̹̳ṅ̉ĝ̓ ͧͥ̓̽tͭͮ̌e͊̐̒s̑̏t͌ͦ͛i̍̒ͬn̉ͦg̅̐͗ ͗ͥ͑ ҉̵ͅtͥ̓e͌̈ ҉̷̨s̍̓͗t͑̂i̓͒ṅ̄g͛̎ ̾͊t̋ͭe̿͊̽sͨ̐t̾ͤi͒̌n̄̌ ҉̸̲̭ǵ ҉͉́́ ̌ͤtͧ̌ȇͩs̊̊t̉̿̈i͊̓n̑̎g̐ ́̑t̓̃ ҉̴̛eͭ̇ͫsͯ̎ ҉̴̛t̑̐͒i̎ͩn̈̃̚ğ̍ ̂̋t͌͌͆ë͂sͮ͊ẗ͗ͭ ҉̸̛i̎̓n̽̓̃g̓ͤ ҉̼̹
    tͦ͗e͒͒ ҉̗̪̳s͊̑̏tͯ̚ǐͭnͦ̇ĝͧ ͐̔͒ṫ͑e͌ͦs̐̄̐t̏̃ ҉́̀iͣn͊͛g̈̓̈ ͩ̋t͋̈eͣ̔s̑̏t͐ͤiͮ̇nͣͭ͑g͌ͦ ͐̃t̓̎̈e̊ͩs̐̽t̆ͤȋ̈n͗ͮg͑̚ ́̂t͗̄ ҉̮͍̬͠ȇͬs̽́t͒͆ ҉̷̞̜i̽ͫn͑̇ǵ̆̚ ̆̚ ҉̴̱͎t͛̿eͪ̈s̄̿tͥͣ̂i̔̃ñ̽g̉̀ ̉͋̊t͋̊ȅ͋sͤ̆ ҉̨̡̝ťͭͥi̿ͯ̓ ҉͠ ҉̠̬ń͋gͪ̒
    t̀̏ẽ̍ ҉͖s̒̋̓t̂i͂̂ ҉̸̪̠͔̮nͬ͑̾͐ ҉̖̲̹g̒̾̑ ͑̚tͦ̒̊eͧ͊sͯ̄t́ͣͣ́ï͆n͋͗g͂̓ ͬ̌ ҉͉̘t͑ͣ̈ěͯsͪ̉t̂̚i͑͑̽ ҉̸̲n̂̾ḡ̅ ͯ͌t̋ͤ ҉̷̛̫ȅ̂̈s̿̍ ҉̼̖t̆̚i̓͐ ҉ ҉̶̝̱nͪͤg̑͒ ̏̔tͯͯĕ̓̈s̅̿͐tͦ̓́iͭ͆n̿͗gͮ̂ ́̒t͋͆e͌̃sͮ͐t̒̓̌ĩ͋n͋ͩ͌͑g͗͑ ́͒̏ ҉̷ͅt̆̈eͣ͂s̃ͭtͨ͒ỉͩ ҉̘͈̠n̆̓ ҉̮̖̪g̍ͪ̚ ҉̦͟͝
    t̍̚e͑̆s̆t͌̈i͌̔n̓ͫͧǧ̈ ͦ̄̚t̄̊e͆̏s̓̏t͆̔iͦ̒͌n̑͋gͨ̎ ̈ͣt̂̎ ҉̠̮͝ͅeͪ ҉̸̧̪͖̞s̿̍̚t̒͋i̎̂n͑ͣ ҉̨͟g̀͂ ̉ͧ̚tͮ́ȇ̾ͮs͋̍tͥ ҉̠͜iͯ́n̓̈ ҉̫̹̼ġ̀ ͬ͋t̽̌̓ ҉̸͞eͩͨ̚sͮ͒t͌ͫi̿͗ͪn̒̀ͯg̓̄ ̋̀t͑̑ ҉̙̮e̍̄s͆͒t͐̉ ҉ ҉͎̯̻i̋̓n̔̿g̿ͥ ͦ̃͒ ҉̴̛t́͑eͯ̽ ҉͈̫̰s̓͛̏t͗̉̍i̎̈nͪ̅ͭg͒̑
    t͌̽ě̑s̊ͣ ҉̼̻͞t̔̓͒ǐ͑nͨͩgͫ̓ ̈̓t́̏ê͆sͭ̓t͗̅i̍̍n̅͐g̀̀ ̒ͭtͮ̈̅ ҉͜ ҉̷͚͍eͣ̑s͊̈t̄̾ỉͨ ҉͟͝ň̽g͑̊ ͧ́t̃͐e̊̑ͩͦš̽tͣ̅̈iͪ͊n̎ͪg̔̓ ̅ͥt̓̾ȇͭ ҉̣̖́s̀̒tͭͭ ҉̴̥̀i͒͗n͗̍gͮ͐͋ ͐ͧ̚tͨ͂ȅͨs̔ͣtͮͫ ҉̴̣̘i͆̾n̈͊gͬ̈̓ ͯͭ ҉̶̨t́̇e͆̀s̎͂t͋̌ͯi͑͗͊n͋̒g̏̿
    t͛̔͌ ҉͓͎e̓̔̉ ҉̨̥̝s̋̌ṫ̐i̾ͣͧn͂̏g̈̐̊ ͋̈t̊̏̀e̿͋͗ ҉̰̬̩̗ͅs̈̊̑ ҉̩̞̮̱t̍́i͗͂n̋̅̽gͣ̃ ̓̓ ҉̵̢̹̻̘t́̋ė̐sͬ̏̽t̔̀i͆̽n̅̈g͊ͤ͆ ̇̚tͥ́ĕ̓̃s͗̊t̍ͫ̍i͗ͨ̾nͪ͑̈g͒̓ ̓̆t͌̐ë̈s̄̔t̒͊̒i̊͆͗nͫ̐gͤ̓ ͛ͨtͩͮ ҉̪͖́ĕ̔sͥͪ ҉̸͘t̒ͫỉ͑nͦ̉͊g̅ ͮ̆ͬtͭͪe̓͊sͤ̊t̃ͭiͬ͂n̂̾ͯg̽͒ ҉̴͠
    t́̌̚e͗ͦ ҉̨̦͇s̆ͭtͭ̈iͧ̾n͗̈g͆ ̅̏t̑ͨe̊ͣs̓ͨ̈t͆̐ĩ͐n̏̈gͣ͊ ͦͦt̅ͧ͌̀e̅̈s̊ͣ͗tͧͯ ҉͔̣́i͒͂nͧ͋gͥ͋ ͋ͧť̆e̋s̎̊t̂ͣi̓ͫ͋n̋̔g̓ͬ ̎̌t̍͐e̒̒s̽ͪt̀͑͊iͣ͌nͬ̓g͂̔ ͯ͊tͣ̍̎ė͌s̓̈̓t̑ͯi̋̑ñ̊g͐ͤ ̑͌t̅̃e͂ͥͩsͤ̒t̓ͮï͆nͪ̊̓g͛ͮ
    t̂̔̿ė̎sͧ͊tͣ̏͐̚i͌̔͆ṅͤg͂ ̇͂t̓̏̆e̓̄sͦ͛ ҉̣͡t̉̌îͬ͑ǹ͒g͑̚ ҉̴̝ ̓̆tͪͫȅ͛s̑ͫͬtͨ̄i͒ͤnͪ̌g̃͒ ̉͐t̒̒e̔́̓ ҉ ҉̛͉s͗̈tͫ̾ͤïͧ̉n̎̈g̽̍ ́̽ ҉͜ ҉̳̠̘͠t̊̾é̇sͫ̔t̊́iͮͣnͭ̓ͮͫg̔̔ ͗͒ ҉͎̘̥̤̠t̓̔eͭͯ̏s͛ͧt͆̿̍i̋̈̇n̄͋g̒̐ ̌̎t̀ͬeͫͣ ҉̨̛̮s̋̓t̎̈ ҉̴̨̘ͅi͌ͨnͩ̇g̈̌
    ẗ̔ȅͯs͐ẗ̈ͩì͑nͯ̈g̃͋̚ ҉̶̖ ͦ̊tͥ̿ ҉̩͞eͤͬs̑̿tͭ͂i͂͊ͨnͣ͛gͮ͛ ̐ͧ̐t̃̚eͮ͆sͧͥ ҉̴̀t̔̎ïͨn͑̑gͪ̃ ̍̅t͐͆e͒̆sͯ͗t̂̚îͬnͫ̉g̃ͬͤ ̊̀ ҉̱̯̫t̔ͥ̓e͂̎̽sͯt͂ͥi͋̍nͭ̒gͩ́̏ ̀̾t͐̈̃ ҉̷̡ê̄sͫ͒t̍͊ͥi̓̈̐nͣͧ̋gͮ̀ ̾͊t̅͐̆e̎ͮ̃ ҉̴̛̲s̊ͬẗ̅i̇̎n̽g̓̒
    t͂ͮe̎̐s̆̃̈t̉͒̃i͑͛nͬͦgͪ͌ ̔ͦ ҉̢͟ẗͪ̀ë̀s̽̒ ҉̶̛t̓͌i͒͌n̐̅͂gͭͯ ͦ̄tͫ̓ͬe͂̓s̎̔t͐ͬĩ͐ ҉̮͢n̓͊gͥͩ ҉͇͈ ̈ͦt̿ͤ ҉̵̘͓̫e͗͊sͨ̐tͧ̈iͤ͗nͮͫ̋ ҉̩͕̲g̈̿ ͪ̒t̊̓e̎ͯs͛̆t͐̈i͐̐̊nͧ͋g͌̔ ͦ͛t̑̎ͣe͂̔̏ ҉̵̯͎s̊̅t͊͆̿î̋nͦ̒g̑̚ ̉̏̀t̅̔e͂̐s̿̃ ҉̣̠̤̱ẗ̔i̽̿̆̅n̈̈g̈̌
    t̂̾̆͆e͌̈̋s͐̒t̋͗̽i̇ͤ ҉̼̕n̓͊ͨgͭ͆ ͤ̿t̊̇é̾̚s̆̾t͆̚i̽̈n͋̑gͧ̎ ̔ͩͮt͆͊eͤ̅ ҉͡͝sͥ͛tͥ̀i͂̋n͌̐g͆̎ ̾ͭ̀tͥ͑ ҉͕͢eͧ̿̆ŝ̀t̾͌i͊̌n̈̚g̎̒ ͐ͣ͌ť̆͛ ҉̠̲̩ë̆sͣ̚t́͑i̋͛̇n̑͐g̏͐ ͂͗ ҉͟͢ ҉̢̱tͨͬͭe̿̉ṡ̒tͩ̆i͑̓ṅͩgͮ̆ ҉̬̰͕̞̫ ͋ͩtͬ͌e̐̎ ҉̴͠s͌̿tͫͤi͋̍n͌͆gͣ͊
    t̂ͤ̚ ҉͍̦eͫͮs̏͋ ҉̸̡t͒͂ ҉̶̛̰i̐͛n̎͆g̈̓̚ ͋̌t̒ͣe͋ͨs̽̆t̿̄iͥͦ ҉̣͘͢nͧ͋g̀̈ ͋̋ť̌e̎ͧŝͤẗͭĩ̐n̈̒g̒͒ ͊ͧ ҉͎̀͟t̓̔e͐͒s̿̓t̀ͭ͒i̅ͮn̆̚g̋͑̑̓ ͐͐t͐͛ ҉̧͙͠è̈ ҉̷̧sͬͤtͩ̔i̊ͯn͋̀ ҉̗̳͇̘̣̦̲̺gͣͥ̏ ͗̉tͭ͑ͬeͦ́ͣ ҉͈̳̥s͑̌t̎̓ȋ̓̏nͪ̉g̀̐͗ ͭͫt͛̚e̊̌s̐ͫtͫ̿ ҉̸̜͟i͑̓ ҉̻͕nͣ͑̈g͌͆
    t̓̓̀ểsͤ͆̀tͮͤi͋̍n͊͗gͯͥ ̂͊͋ ҉͚̩̭͜t͆͗ë͂s̃̆̃t̆͗͋i̓̓nͮ̿ͪĝ̓ ͦͬt̅ͩ̈eͯͤsͥ̿̇t̿͑i͊̒nͤ̑ǵ͊ ͐̐t͋͌e͆̔ ҉̴̹̳́s̓̍t̆̏ͥi͂̈nͧ͋g̈͌ ͒̀t͒̽̈ẽ͛s̚̚t͆̿iͯͩnͦ͒g̏̅ ҉͇ͅ ͧ̿t̋͑e͆̃̎s̏ͩt͊̉iͯ̿n̽̅g͌̓ ͧ͋t͗̃͂eͬ͒s̿͐ ҉͟ ҉̴̰t͛͛ ҉̴̛̲iͤͨ ҉̩̪n͊̀g̉̅
    tͩ̚ ҉̣͘eͭ̂ ҉̸̧sͨ̓ͮtͭ͗ī̅n̔̆ǵ̆̈ ҉̨͚̭̭ ̉̽tͦ͆e̾ͨsͪ̉̄t̋̿̈iͪ̎n̈̚g͆͆ ̑͌tͭ̓ͯe̓͋ ҉̡͘s͛̓t̊ͫi̒ͭnͪ̅g̋̔ ̇͆̀tͥͫe͌̄s͌̈ ҉̟̼̘t̽̊i̍͐nͯͪ ҉̵̩͝g̿̂̌ ͐̐t͋̈e͂͌̓ṡͫt̒͂i̊́̌̚nͭ̅gͫ̎ ҉ ҉̗͖̭ ̈̈ͥtͧ͋e͋ͬͬs̆̑ṫ̂i͛͗͋n̒̀g͊ͭ ͥ̑t̅̾é̾s̀͒t͑̓ ҉̠͠i̓͆n̔g̓̀͑
    t̒ͭėͤs̀ͫt͆̿iͯͭn͊gͬͣ ̐̒t͛ͯ̿eͧ̋s̔̉̔tͧ̓i͋ͪn̾ͥ ҉̠͡gͨ̿ ͣ̉t̋ͦͨeͩͯs͑͑ ҉̴͞t̃ͧìͫn̊́g̑ͭ ͪ̋t̉̿eͧ̎̈s͐͋t̔̂i͒̑n̓͐g̐́ ͪ͆͑ṫ̍ ҉̜e̅s̏ͣ͋tͦ̊i̓̂́n̐͆gͩ́̚ ̿̀tͮͣeͬ̿sͭ̓̃tͧ͗ ҉͕͇͎i̋ͮ̈n̅̔ ҉ ҉̥̳gͬ̅ ̋͂t͂̍ ҉͙̬͡e͌̚sͮ͆̅tͧͩ̇i̊̾n̓͂g̓̉
    t̿̊e̾ͬs̀ͫtͯͮiͯͧnͣ̅gͩ́ ҉̧͡ ̔̒t̐̃eͤͮś́ ҉̷̖t̊̐i̊̏n͆͐g͐̌ ̉̇t̓͋eͩͨs͛ͦtͫ͌iͧͬnͯ̓g͗̃̚ ҉̘͚ ͮ̄tͫ̏͛e̋̎s͗̈t̋ͭiͫ̒ ҉͓̕nͣ̈gͧͩ ͧ̔tͯ͌̄e͊̊ͭs̿́ ҉̴̶̗̦t̔̂ ҉̡i̔̅͆nͣ͑gͧ̿ ̄ͨt̔ͩ͂e̋ͪs͊̑t͂ͭĩ̓ñ̊gͤ̽͋ ͣ̈ẗͧeͦ̅s͌̚t̓̒i͑̽n̅̆gͩ̐
    t͆ͬē͑s̍̈t̒ͫ͛ ҉͜͞i̐ͯn̓̓̄ ҉̹̲͍ͅg̊̆ ҉ ҉̶ ҉̟̘̤̫ ̍̑ ҉̷͈t̀̅e̊͛s̔ͧtͥ́̌i̓̈n̍ͣg̽̽ ̋̉t͂̓ͨeͦ̓ ҉͇͠s̋̈t̊ͨͪi͂̄ͪͭn͋͌g̊͗̉ ̓̓ṫ́e͆̏̈͋s̍ͮt̂͂i̾ͩ ҉̖̪nͪg͒͛͌ ͧͭ ҉̀͟t̂͂ě̂s͐ͫ ҉̪͡ͅtͣͦ͂i̇ͩn̆̓ͫg͋̚ ҉̹̥͠ ̀̐t̅́e͌ͪs͋̀t̔̚i̊ͩn̐ͮg͆͆ ͐͐ẗ̌e͛̆s͑̈t̃͐ ҉̷̨ ҉̲̺̺i͋n͋̿gͯͧ
    t͊ͫ ҉̢͎͠e͗̃ś̊ ҉̷̺͙̙t̍͛̀i̾̃͋ñ͂ğ͒͋ ͐̐ ҉̝͍͘t̽̓e̐̒s͗̂ ҉̶̰t͒̉iͤͪͨń͗gͬ̆ ̅̚ẗ̅̃ȅ̐̿s̊͛t̑̈͐i̅ ҉͈͙̣͉͢n̉͐̈ ҉͉̬gͥ̌ͤ ͤ̓̅t̽̀ͩe̎͋s͗̿t́̔i̍́n̔̿g͌̈ͣ ̅̈t̏ͦe̐ͣs̒̅t̆͆ỉ̀n̒ͬǧ̌ ̋̅t́̓ẽͥ ҉̧͙̘̜sͯ̿t͊̈ǐͪn͋ͨ̂g̽ͨͦ̃ ͗̾t͌̽̽ë͗ ҉͙͓s̐ͮ ҉̡̤͞t̓͐ͩi͂ͯn̓̿ġͯ
    t̅͌e̍̀̚s̾͛t̆̇iͫ͌n̾̎g̓͋ ̇̊t͆͋eͧ̊s̓̓t̄͂i̊͂ṅ̎ǵ̚ ̏̑tͧͪeͯ̽sͫ̇t́̔i̋̔n̍̈g͑ ̋ͧt͌ͤé̄s̍ť̅i̅͑ ҉̱̹͙̝̝̠nͧ͋g͊̚ ̈͛t̾̑eͧ͌͒s̔̆ͨṫͧiͥ̈n͋̈ͦg̿̿̓̽̅ ͫ̈t̓̽e͐͐ ҉̖͇s̃͂͋t̐̓̓ī̑̒ń̈gͭ͆ ͣ̍t̀͋eͣ̿ ҉̴͝sͨͥ̓tͯ̿ïͯͫn͛̿̈ ҉̷̛̫g͑ͭ̊
    t̂̊ ҉̻̳̙͢e͋̊͊s̃̀t͐̎i̔̀nͧ̊g͛ͥ ͣ̈t̊ͫe̽͐̌s̐̽t͑̓i͋̔ ҉͖͜nͯͤg̃͒ ͋̽t͗ͥͧeͭ̎̂s̄̈t̽̓ĩ́ ҉̪͟n̋͑g̊́ ҉̼̖̗ ̑ẗͪͤè̚s̑ͥt͆̿ ҉̯ͅi̽̏n̒ͭg̈ͩ ̋̎ ҉̳͇tͭͨ͗e͑ͣs̎̂͗ṫ̑̈i̿̉ͨ̀n̈̌ͭg̈͑ ͨͦ͆tͮ̒e̓́s͗̿t͆̎i̎ͫ ҉̲̟n̊̈ġͫͮ ̂t́̈̅e̋̏s̑̏t̽͒i̽́ ҉̸̥n͌̐g͊̉͐ ҉̘͎ͅ
    tͨ̒eͫ́sͯ̎t̾̈ ҉̧́iͩ̈́nͭ̒g̿̈ ̌̆t̏ͧe̅̂sͩ͌t͌̃iͥ̋n͛̋g̓ͯ ̄ͫt̂̔ė̎̓s̔͐tͧ͊͒i͛̈ͫnͯ̈ğͣ ̏͆t͌̈e̽̓ͯs̒̉t̊͆ ҉̸̛i͆ͥñ̓ ҉̤͠gͭ̑ ̒͑ṫ̄ͭë̏ ҉̕͢s̍ ҉̨̘̠ͅt̃ͥͬiͩͪn̏̎ ҉̳͔gͫ̃ ͫ̓͑tͮ̈è̓s̔̉t̍ͫ̈i̒̀n͗̓g͂̿̄ ̍̇ ҉̴̻͔tͣ̀eͣ̔̈s͂̃ ҉̮͎̲́t̍ͣ̚ ҉̵͞i͒̑nͣ̑ǵ͛̿
```

The response has an infinite number of words sequence **'Testing'**. This continues for eternity!!!
The first three lines print **undefined** and then some texts with a lot of 'H'.
There is also a name in the starting called **'Carl Pilcher'**.

After all this, I have spent a whole lot of time fixing this, but no luck.
I have removed both firebase-tools and firebase globally and locally respectively, along with node-modules and again installed firebase-tools globally, it still results in the same response.
I have cleaned all the cache related to npm, yarn, and anything and everything related to firebase in my system, but no difference.


Just to inform, commands other than firebase are working fine and normally on my system .
After spending a lot of time, I am clueless, really need some instructions to quickly figure out what's getting wrong. I have found nothing of the sort on the internet so far. If anybody has any idea about it, please share.
If someone has experienced some similar issue, please contact.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A developer added a "new American flag module" to colors.js library yesterday in version v1.4.44-liberty-2 that he then pushed to GitHub and npm. The infinite loop introduced in the code will keep running indefinitely; printing the gibberish non-ASCII character sequence endlessly on the console for any applications that use the library.

It stems from the winston logging dep requiring logform that in turn requires colors https://github.com/winstonjs/logform/blob/7e18114c6426e4b69a76b1d8a023c87801421677/package.json#L31

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same bug. The problem is due to a Firebase GitHub action that uses the colors.js library. You can check the solution status in the following issue: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy/issues/188

Answer (score 1):

Had that same issue today!
after hours of trying probably EVERYTHING:

uninstall firebase-tools by running:

```
npm uninstall -g firebase-tools
```

then reinstall by running:

```
curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash
```

(if you havent installed curl command, follow the instructions on terminal now)

then i tried "firebase login" one more time, getting:
"-bash: /usr/local/bin/firebase: No such file or directory"

if you face it, follow the instructions under "Steps to reproduce"
here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1851
(actually removes any version left i guess)

then reinstall with:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

now try to:

```
firebase login
```

don't ask me how but... solved my problem! hope it will help you!

Comment: Thanks for your input. It was all happening due to the bug in 'colors' package. Has been resolved just now. Here is the issue: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy/issues/188